# Google Data Studio Geo Map stays blank while using Lat,Long as Dimension

Tags: visualization, geocoding, latitude-longitude, looker-studio, geomap

I want to use `Google Data Studio` to visualize the location of NGO´s in Europe. Some of these share the same HQ Location in the Data e.g. `Italy Rome`. Idea is to transfer these into Lat,Long coordinates and slightly manipulate the values to show them with their name in the `GMaps bubble diagram`. The original data is unfit, because the digram cannot display multiple tooltips/names for the same location.

I have been following this guide https://michaelhoweely.com/2020/05/04/how-to-build-a-custom-google-map-in-data-studio-using-google-sheets-and-geocode/ to do the Geo Coding of the locations.

Problem is that the Geo Chart goes blank if I choose `Lat,Long` as the location dimension. Even the original data (not modified by me) will cause the same issue.

[GDataStudio_Lat_Long_Vis_Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84mOD.png)

Any idea of what I am doing wrong here or having a better idea of how to do the visualization?

Answer (score 3):

You also have to make sure you change the type to GEO, as it sometimes defaults to ABC or numeric.

Answer (score 1):

It may help to concatenate the latitude and longitude values to follow the WKT format, as shown below.

```
CONCAT(<longitude_column>, ", ", <latitude_column>)
```

In the current state, the latitude and longitude are reversed, so the error is probably caused by each value exceeding the default range for latitude and longitude.